# Debugging of Linea pro 5 using iPhone5s for credit card swiping

Tags: ios

I am working on swiping the credit card using Linea  pro 5. Is there any way to debug the code when iPhone 5s is connected with the Linea Pro. By using Linea pro4 am able to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Linea Pro 4 and connect it to iPhone 5 by using the iphone 4 adapter.

Answer (score 0):

https://ipcmobile.com/products/ios-peripherals/linea-pro-5/ 
My suggestion, It's not support iPhone5s now!